# Undefined variable including php file

Tags: php

I'm sorry if the question is already been made many times but I cannot figure out.

My site structure is:

- root

  - Forms

    - FormHouse
    - FormUser

In the root folder I have a file classes.php

```
<?php
  include("config.php");
  include("class.mysql.php");
  ... code ...
?>
```

This file is included in th file root/Forms/FormHouse/FormHouse.php

```
<?php 

  include('../../classes.php');

  session_start();

  print_r(get_included_files());

  $db = new MySQL("$db_name", "$db_user", "$db_psw", "$host");
  if (!$db) 
  die($db->Error());

?>
```

I also try:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\..\classes.php');
```

Here I get "Undefined variable" on $db_user, $db_name, $db_psw, $host.

Looking to included files, the classes.php is present:

```
Array 
( [0] => D:\xampp\htdocs\site\Forms\FormHouse\FormHouse.php 
  [1] => D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes.php 
  [2] => D:\xampp\php\pear\Config.php 
  [3] => D:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR.php 
  [4] => D:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR5.php 
  [5] => D:\xampp\php\pear\Config\Container.php 
  [6] => D:\xampp\htdocs\site\class.MySQL.php 
)
```

Why this happens? The include order matter?

Comment: Are these set in one of the included files?

Comment: Silly question: are you sure `classes.php` sets those variables?

Comment: I assume it's because you haven't got any `config.php` (that PEAR one is in your path and _not_ the one your want)? Hint: (1) always _require_  files you definitely need (2) enable display_errors & set error_reporting high while developing. And (3) never include relative to your working dir, use `__DIR__` (or possibly a document root) to be sure were your files are.

Comment: @Wrikken He seems to have error reporting enabled, since he's getting the "Undefined variable" errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions @Wrikken . The problem was that the current path was root/Forms/FormHouse and, of course, the includes in the classes.php does not work. I added chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); before them and now all seems to work.

Comment: @Barzo: glad to hear it works, however, I would like to advocate against `chdir()`, as it is a beginning without end: you include file `A`, which `chdir()`'s to its dir, and includes `dir/B`, which in turn might `chdir()` to it's dir, so is `A` to `chdir()` to its own dir then after every include or require? What after every possible function call which can call `chdir()`? Including like `require __DIR__.'/i/know/this/path.php'` works a charm, and does not need function calls or working dir changes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

before the includes in classes.php has solved the problem.